# Counting number of model instances

Tags: django, django-models, unique

Suppose I have a model called `User`, with a field called `name`. How can I determine whether a `User` instance, with a particular name `Andrew`, already exists in the database?

I could do:

```
matched_users = User.objects.filter(name = 'Andrew')
if matched_users.count() == 0:
    # It does not exist
else:
    # It does exist
```

But is there a way I can do this in one line, without having to retrieve all instances and then count them?

Comment: This already does what you want. Because Django lazily evaluates querysets, it won't retrieve all instances. The database won't be hit until the `count()` call. That said, `exists()` is the more straightforward way.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use [exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists):

```
if User.objects.filter(name='Andrew').exists():
    # do something
```

But there might me multiple users with same name. You might want to lookup on some unique field e.g. username or email

If you want to insist using `count` method then it can be written as:

```
if User.objects.filter(name = 'Andrew').count() > 0:
    # exists
```

Answer (score 2):

[Ask for forgiveness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python): let it try to create a duplicate and handle [`IntegrityError`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#django.db.IntegrityError) exception.

You need to define [`unique=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique) on the `name` field for this to work:

> Field.unique
>
> This is enforced at the database level and by model validation. If you
>   try to save a model with a duplicate value in a unique field, a
>   django.db.IntegrityError will be raised by the model’s save() method.

Comment: Asking for forgiveness is not so straightforward when it comes to interacting with the database. For example, an `IntegrityError` will spoil the current transaction regardless of whether or not you catch it.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry I could have posted `exists()` solution, but I just like to provide alternative solutions viewing from another perspective. And, depending on the use case - for example, if the OP checks for the existence of a user with the same name before creating a user, both solutions have right to exist. Less roundtrips to the database if this is the case. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: My point is just to warn readers against blindly applying the EAFP idiom - so familiar to Python developers - without carefully thinking about the interactions with the database. I agree with you that for some use cases this will be the more efficient solution.